# Is there a way to contact my Chrome extension users?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

My Chrome extension was taken down from the webstore after a copyright violation complain. I tried reaching the complainant and sorting out the matter but he is not responding.

I am contemplating launching a new copy of the extension but **I don't want to lose my existing user base**. **Is there a way by which I could notify the existing users to install the new version?**

Getting a list of users to send a mass email or a mechanism to notify them from the official site would do.

Comment: You really should not do that. Repeated violations could result in your developer account being banned.

Comment: With `new version` you mean `new extension`? If it is a new version for the same extension, the users will automatically be informed about the new version. It will even be installed automatically (if users didn't change the update setting).

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan - The bone of contention is the name of the extension. I mean to launch the new extension by renaming it and taking care of other violations. In my opinion, that is fair, right?

Comment: @devnull69 - I don't mean to upgrade the extension to a newer version. I want to launch the same extension under a different name separately.

Comment: Ok, got it. Technically speaking it won't be the `same` extension any more. Nevertheless, there is no way for an extension developer to inform users of a specific extension directly. The only way would have been to alter the `old` extension so that it shows a link to the new one. But as the old extension has been removed from the web store, I'm afraid this option has been destroyed for you

Comment: I suggest to fix the issue that caused the take-down and request a review to undo the take-down. Either post to the chromium-apps group or contact Joe Marini (without spaces at google dot com), explain the situation and request a review.

Comment: @RobW - I fixed the issue and submitted it for a Manual Review by the Chrome webstore team. But they responded back saying that they require a mail from the original complainant to reinstate the extension.

Meanwhile, I'll try contacting Joe Marini on this issue.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Should have renamed the extension before it was taken down by publishing an update.

Comment: @ZigMandel - I would have if they had sent me prior notice. All I got was a take-down notification from Google.

Comment: maybe the violation was too obvious? what was the extension name

Comment: I'd rather not reveal the name because the concerned person just responded and we are sorting out the matter.

However, Yes, the violation was obvious and in plain sight. But the timeline of events raises questions.

When I had just launched the extension around 8 months ago, I mailed them (they have a perennially open challenge to design a browser extension to extend the functionality) and they applauded it too. (I gave them the link to webstore)

Comment: Fast-forward 8 months and suddenly out-of-the-blue, when extension had considerable amount of users and their is a growing criticism against them for not providing the functionality they directly go and take down my extension.

I might be reading too much into the situation. But what surprised me was that they could have at least let me know their reservations rather than directly blocking it. I would have more than happy to comply.